# How to send a POST request with a C# class?

Tags: c#, xml, post

I made an API that accepts a XML file and send it to Firebase:

```
// POST api/<getXmlController>
[HttpPost(Name = "postXml")]
public async Task<FatturaElettronicaType> PostFile(IFormFile upload)
{
    XmlSerializer ser = new(typeof(FatturaElettronicaType));
    FatturaElettronicaType fe = (FatturaElettronicaType)ser!.Deserialize(upload!.OpenReadStream()!)!;
    await firebase.AddFe(fe);
    return fe;
}
```

Now I'm trying to make a console application that sends some dummy content as a C# class, how could I get this to work?

```
        int? posts = null;

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Quanti post?");
            posts = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        } while (posts == null);

        for (int i = 0; i < posts; i++)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("api/xml", randFe());
        }
```

The `randFe()` function returns an object of my class, but it needs a HttpContent.

Comment: Are you wanting to send a XML file or the contents of the XML?

Comment: I'm trying to send an XML file